# Unable to terminate other apps when sandbox

Tags: swift, macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I developed an app that terminates other apps, It works perfectly when it's not sandboxed.

```
NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplication.forceTerminate()
```

**Issue:**
When the app is sandbox I cannot terminate other apps.

**Question:** 
How can allow my app to have the capability to terminate other apps when sandbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When the app is sandbox I cannot terminate other apps.

Correct. That is the essence of the sandbox: your application is isolated from other applications, and cannot interact with them outside of certain specific channels.

> How can allow my app to have the capability to terminate other apps when sandbox?

You can't. (At least, not in the general case.)